# Senescence in space

Tags: senescence

How is senescence of individual eukaryotic cells and tissues affected by gravity and zero-gravity environments? In other words, can eukaryotic cells live forever in space (given the appropriate nutrients)?

Comment: Why would you suspect this? There’s not really any good reason to think so.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was thinking that the zero-gravity environment might lead to some cell signalling to for example create more telomerae.. something like that...

Comment: Wouldnt all the radiation be a factor too?

Comment: @RoSiv Yes it would